# Append variable value to form Input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to append numeric value stored in one variable to form input fields.

Let's Say

```
var b= 5;
var text=$("#dropdown_id").val();
```

I want to append value of variable b in dropdown_id .

My expected result is  #dropdown_id5

Comment: `.val(5)`? just use the value

Comment: @AmitJoki Values of b changes every time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use string concatenation:

```
$("#dropdown_id" + b).val()
```